# Lucene query syntax in Azure Search: and binary operator

Tags: lucene, azure-cognitive-search

Azure Search documentation denotes that in *Lucene query syntax* in Azure Search next "and" operators can be used: `AND` `&` `+`, but why I am getting different sets of results for next two semantically equivale queries:

```
search=tec AND pro&queryType=full&$count=true
search=tec %26 pro&queryType=full&$count=true //%26 is encoded &
```

Edited: fixed ampersand encoded code, thanks *femtoRgon*

Comment: You've got the wrong ASCII code. %25 = "%", %26 = "&"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. This is a bug in our documentation. Please use && (%26%26, url encoded) for the operator AND and || (%7C%7C, url encoded) for OR. We will fix our documentation asap.

Nate